# Spring Boot and html not rendering javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, src

I am trying to cache some results of a js script. (note this is working for other things like raw string data returned from a service, just not for this. Also note this is the first time I am trying to do it with a script and .js file.

Working:
in html:

```
<script src="https://www.notmydomain.com/script.js?param1=blah"></script>
```

not working:
in html:

```
<script src="/script.js?param1=blah"></script>
```

in @RestConroller method (from System.out.println's I know its returning the exact same thing as when I call the script directly):

```
    @GetMapping("/script.js") 
    public String script(Model model, @RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams) {
        String parameters = inputParameterBuilder.buildParametersString(allRequestParams);

        String js = pagesCacheService.getPage("script.js"+parameters, null, String.class);
        if(null == js) {
            js = resttemplate.getForObject("https://www.notmydomain.com/script.js" + parameters, String.class);
            pagesCacheService.updatePage("script.js"+parameters, js, String.class);
        }

        return js;
    }
```

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: What does the network tab in the Chrome dev tools say to your problem? Do you get a 200 status? Is the body correct? What if you curl the URL or open it directly in your browser: http://yourdomain/script.js?param=bla ? Does that work? Are the headers identical for the different requests? Content-Type set to "text/javascript" in your RestController?

Comment: 1. I should have known the issue.  2 why do I always forget to f12 in chrome?  I guess its b/c I'm still fairly new to front end dev.

Comment: Chrome dev tools are your best friends ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue: @GetMapping(value = "/script.js",produces = "text/javascript")